Qgis2threejs - Is it possible to display a vector line as a wall with varying 'other side Z' values?
I have a 3d polyline vector layer that I would like to display as a wall in qgis2threejs. I can view the extruded wall by assigning a value to the 'Other side Z' field, however the base of the wall is fixed to that absolute Z value. I would like to display the base of the wall as being relative to the z value of the polyline, so the bottom of the wall varies along the z-axis in a constant relative distance to the top of the wall. Is this possible? Is there a workaround to make this visualisation, such as creating a vertical 3d polygon?
